# Display tag external sort overriden?

Tags: sorting, displaytag

I am using display tag and spring mvc. 
Basically, i have a simple table like this. Note the use of **external**.

```
    <display:table id="tableId" name="data" sort="external" defaultsort="1" sort="external">
  <display:column property="id" title="ID" sortable="true" sortName="id" />
  <display:column property="firstName" sortable="true" sortName="firstName" title="First Name" />
  <display:column property="lastName" sortable="true" sortName="lastName" title="Last Name" />
  <display:column property="address" sortable="true" sortName="address" title="Email Address"/>
</display:table>
```

On the controller side, i get the sorted column index and the sort order.

```
String c = request.getAttribute(new ParamEncoder("tableId").encodeParameterName(TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_SORT));
```

To get the order (ASC/DESC):

```
  String order = request.getAttribute(new ParamEncoder("tableId").encodeParameterName(TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_ORDER)));
```

All this is working fine. For the last step i used customized comparator to sort my list and put it back into the attribute "data" mapped himself to the table (see display tag "name" property).

```
public void populateModel(Model model, HttpRequest request){
     String c = request.getAttribute(new ParamEncoder("tableId").encodeParameterName(TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_SORT));

    // here the comparator is computed with column and order value eg
    Comparator comp = new DefaultComparator();
    if(c == 1){
         comp  = new NumericComparator();
    }
    List<Employe> list = Collection.sort(dao.getEmployee(), comp );
    model.addAttribute("data", list);

    // here the list is sorted properly

    return "mypage";           
 }
```

Unfortunatly the display in the final jsp does not care about order in the list. It seem's something is overriding to a default and alphanumeric sorter...so even if i use my NumericComparator the column is still wrong sorted and i assume the "list" object has been sorted back by the librairie before the display.

To summup:

1. Get display tag indexes : **ok**
2. Sort the list and put it back to jsp : **ok** (list is sorted depending on display tag params in the controller)
3. Display the sorted list in the jsp side with display tag : **KO** (the library do not care about list order, sorting it with default sort)
4. Display the sorted list in the jsp side without display tag : **OK**

Any got the explanation about this, is there something wrong or missing ?

Comment: Don't you want `String c = request.Parameter(new ParamEncoder("tableId").encodeParameterName(TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_SORT));` rather than request.getAttribute(....);

Comment: no, i get all the parameters. all is fine. the problem is in the jsp, the library don't cares about  custom sort and i can't understand why... if i display the list without display tag, the sort order is fine